# Layout with rounded corners using vector for background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, vector, shapes

I have constraint layout using xml as a background.

Constraintlayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fr_main_masters"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_background_wave"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ic_background_wave.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
      <stroke
          android:color="#B1BCBE" />
      <corners android:radius="16dp" />
      <padding
          android:bottom="0dp"
          android:left="0dp"
          android:right="0dp"
          android:top="0dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_group_wave_backg"/>
</layer-list>
```

ic_group_wave_backg.xml (here should be much more paths - each path is a wave - because stack limits I have put only few upper waves as a code)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="199dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="199">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,1L340.82,3.92C338.46,4.81 335.85,4.81 333.49,3.92L329.42,2.38C327.06,1.49 324.46,1.49 322.1,2.38L318.03,3.92C315.67,4.81 313.07,4.81 310.71,3.92L306.64,2.38C304.28,1.49 301.67,1.49 299.31,2.38L295.25,3.92C292.89,4.81 290.28,4.81 287.92,3.92L283.86,2.38C281.5,1.49 278.89,1.49 276.53,2.38L272.46,3.92C270.1,4.81 267.5,4.81 265.14,3.92L261.07,2.38C258.71,1.49 256.11,1.49 253.75,2.38L249.68,3.92C247.32,4.81 244.71,4.81 242.35,3.92L238.29,2.38C235.93,1.49 233.32,1.49 230.96,2.38L226.9,3.92C224.54,4.81 221.93,4.81 219.57,3.92L215.5,2.38C213.14,1.49 210.54,1.49 208.18,2.38L204.11,3.92C201.75,4.81 199.15,4.81 196.79,3.92L192.72,2.38C190.36,1.49 187.75,1.49 185.39,2.38L181.33,3.92C178.97,4.81 176.36,4.81 174,3.92L169.94,2.38C167.57,1.49 164.97,1.49 162.61,2.38L158.54,3.92C156.18,4.81 153.58,4.81 151.22,3.92L147.15,2.38C144.79,1.49 142.19,1.49 139.83,2.38L135.76,3.92C133.4,4.81 130.79,4.81 128.43,3.92L124.37,2.38C122.01,1.49 119.4,1.49 117.04,2.38L112.97,3.92C110.61,4.81 108.01,4.81 105.65,3.92L101.58,2.38C99.22,1.49 96.62,1.49 94.26,2.38L90.19,3.92C87.83,4.81 85.23,4.81 82.87,3.92L78.8,2.38C76.44,1.49 73.83,1.49 71.47,2.38L67.41,3.92C65.05,4.81 62.44,4.81 60.08,3.92L56.02,2.38C53.65,1.49 51.05,1.49 48.69,2.38L44.62,3.92C42.26,4.81 39.66,4.81 37.3,3.92L33.23,2.38C30.87,1.49 28.27,1.49 25.91,2.38L21.84,3.92C19.48,4.81 16.87,4.81 14.51,3.92L10.45,2.38C8.09,1.49 5.48,1.49 3.12,2.38L-0.94,3.92C-3.31,4.81 -5.91,4.81 -8.27,3.92L-16,1"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,5.58L340.83,8.51C338.46,9.41 335.84,9.41 333.47,8.51L329.44,6.98C327.07,6.08 324.45,6.08 322.08,6.98L318.05,8.51C315.68,9.41 313.06,9.41 310.69,8.51L306.66,6.98C304.29,6.08 301.67,6.08 299.3,6.98L295.27,8.51C292.89,9.41 290.27,9.41 287.9,8.51L283.88,6.98C281.5,6.08 278.88,6.08 276.51,6.98L272.48,8.51C270.11,9.41 267.49,9.41 265.12,8.51L261.09,6.98C258.72,6.08 256.1,6.08 253.73,6.98L249.7,8.51C247.33,9.41 244.71,9.41 242.34,8.51L238.31,6.98C235.93,6.08 233.32,6.08 230.94,6.98L226.91,8.51C224.54,9.41 221.92,9.41 219.55,8.51L215.52,6.98C213.15,6.08 210.53,6.08 208.16,6.98L204.13,8.51C201.76,9.41 199.14,9.41 196.77,8.51L192.74,6.98C190.37,6.08 187.75,6.08 185.38,6.98L181.35,8.51C178.98,9.41 176.35,9.41 173.98,8.51L169.96,6.98C167.58,6.08 164.96,6.08 162.59,6.98L158.56,8.51C156.19,9.41 153.57,9.41 151.2,8.51L147.17,6.98C144.8,6.08 142.18,6.08 139.81,6.98L135.78,8.51C133.41,9.41 130.79,9.41 128.41,8.51L124.39,6.98C122.01,6.08 119.39,6.08 117.02,6.98L112.99,8.51C110.62,9.41 108,9.41 105.63,8.51L101.6,6.98C99.23,6.08 96.61,6.08 94.24,6.98L90.21,8.51C87.84,9.41 85.22,9.41 82.85,8.51L78.82,6.98C76.45,6.08 73.83,6.08 71.45,6.98L67.43,8.51C65.05,9.41 62.43,9.41 60.06,8.51L56.03,6.98C53.66,6.08 51.04,6.08 48.67,6.98L44.64,8.51C42.27,9.41 39.65,9.41 37.28,8.51L33.25,6.98C30.88,6.08 28.26,6.08 25.89,6.98L21.86,8.51C19.49,9.41 16.87,9.41 14.49,8.51L10.47,6.98C8.09,6.08 5.47,6.08 3.1,6.98L-0.93,8.51C-3.3,9.41 -5.92,9.41 -8.29,8.51L-16,5.58"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,10.19L340.82,13.11C338.46,14 335.85,14 333.49,13.11L329.42,11.57C327.06,10.68 324.46,10.68 322.1,11.57L318.03,13.11C315.67,14 313.07,14 310.71,13.11L306.64,11.57C304.28,10.68 301.67,10.68 299.31,11.57L295.25,13.11C292.89,14 290.28,14 287.92,13.11L283.86,11.57C281.5,10.68 278.89,10.68 276.53,11.57L272.46,13.11C270.1,14 267.5,14 265.14,13.11L261.07,11.57C258.71,10.68 256.11,10.68 253.75,11.57L249.68,13.11C247.32,14 244.71,14 242.35,13.11L238.29,11.57C235.93,10.68 233.32,10.68 230.96,11.57L226.9,13.11C224.54,14 221.93,14 219.57,13.11L215.5,11.57C213.14,10.68 210.54,10.68 208.18,11.57L204.11,13.11C201.75,14 199.15,14 196.79,13.11L192.72,11.57C190.36,10.68 187.75,10.68 185.39,11.57L181.33,13.11C178.97,14 176.36,14 174,13.11L169.94,11.57C167.57,10.68 164.97,10.68 162.61,11.57L158.54,13.11C156.18,14 153.58,14 151.22,13.11L147.15,11.57C144.79,10.68 142.19,10.68 139.83,11.57L135.76,13.11C133.4,14 130.79,14 128.43,13.11L124.37,11.57C122.01,10.68 119.4,10.68 117.04,11.57L112.97,13.11C110.61,14 108.01,14 105.65,13.11L101.58,11.57C99.22,10.68 96.62,10.68 94.26,11.57L90.19,13.11C87.83,14 85.23,14 82.87,13.11L78.8,11.57C76.44,10.68 73.83,10.68 71.47,11.57L67.41,13.11C65.05,14 62.44,14 60.08,13.11L56.02,11.57C53.65,10.68 51.05,10.68 48.69,11.57L44.62,13.11C42.26,14 39.66,14 37.3,13.11L33.23,11.57C30.87,10.68 28.27,10.68 25.91,11.57L21.84,13.11C19.48,14 16.87,14 14.51,13.11L10.45,11.57C8.09,10.68 5.48,10.68 3.12,11.57L-0.94,13.11C-3.31,14 -5.91,14 -8.27,13.11L-16,10.19"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,14.8L340.82,17.72C338.46,18.61 335.85,18.61 333.49,17.72L329.42,16.18C327.06,15.29 324.46,15.29 322.1,16.18L318.03,17.72C315.67,18.61 313.07,18.61 310.71,17.72L306.64,16.18C304.28,15.29 301.67,15.29 299.31,16.18L295.25,17.72C292.89,18.61 290.28,18.61 287.92,17.72L283.86,16.18C281.5,15.29 278.89,15.29 276.53,16.18L272.46,17.72C270.1,18.61 267.5,18.61 265.14,17.72L261.07,16.18C258.71,15.29 256.11,15.29 253.75,16.18L249.68,17.72C247.32,18.61 244.71,18.61 242.35,17.72L238.29,16.18C235.93,15.29 233.32,15.29 230.96,16.18L226.9,17.72C224.54,18.61 221.93,18.61 219.57,17.72L215.5,16.18C213.14,15.29 210.54,15.29 208.18,16.18L204.11,17.72C201.75,18.61 199.15,18.61 196.79,17.72L192.72,16.18C190.36,15.29 187.75,15.29 185.39,16.18L181.33,17.72C178.97,18.61 176.36,18.61 174,17.72L169.94,16.18C167.57,15.29 164.97,15.29 162.61,16.18L158.54,17.72C156.18,18.61 153.58,18.61 151.22,17.72L147.15,16.18C144.79,15.29 142.19,15.29 139.83,16.18L135.76,17.72C133.4,18.61 130.79,18.61 128.43,17.72L124.37,16.18C122.01,15.29 119.4,15.29 117.04,16.18L112.97,17.72C110.61,18.61 108.01,18.61 105.65,17.72L101.58,16.18C99.22,15.29 96.62,15.29 94.26,16.18L90.19,17.72C87.83,18.61 85.23,18.61 82.87,17.72L78.8,16.18C76.44,15.29 73.83,15.29 71.47,16.18L67.41,17.72C65.05,18.61 62.44,18.61 60.08,17.72L56.02,16.18C53.65,15.29 51.05,15.29 48.69,16.18L44.62,17.72C42.26,18.61 39.66,18.61 37.3,17.72L33.23,16.18C30.87,15.29 28.27,15.29 25.91,16.18L21.84,17.72C19.48,18.61 16.87,18.61 14.51,17.72L10.45,16.18C8.09,15.29 5.48,15.29 3.12,16.18L-0.94,17.72C-3.31,18.61 -5.91,18.61 -8.27,17.72L-16,14.8"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,19.38L340.83,22.31C338.46,23.21 335.84,23.21 333.47,22.31L329.44,20.78C327.07,19.88 324.45,19.88 322.08,20.78L318.05,22.31C315.68,23.21 313.06,23.21 310.69,22.31L306.66,20.78C304.29,19.88 301.67,19.88 299.3,20.78L295.27,22.31C292.89,23.21 290.27,23.21 287.9,22.31L283.88,20.78C281.5,19.88 278.88,19.88 276.51,20.78L272.48,22.31C270.11,23.21 267.49,23.21 265.12,22.31L261.09,20.78C258.72,19.88 256.1,19.88 253.73,20.78L249.7,22.31C247.33,23.21 244.71,23.21 242.34,22.31L238.31,20.78C235.93,19.88 233.32,19.88 230.94,20.78L226.91,22.31C224.54,23.21 221.92,23.21 219.55,22.31L215.52,20.78C213.15,19.88 210.53,19.88 208.16,20.78L204.13,22.31C201.76,23.21 199.14,23.21 196.77,22.31L192.74,20.78C190.37,19.88 187.75,19.88 185.38,20.78L181.35,22.31C178.98,23.21 176.35,23.21 173.98,22.31L169.96,20.78C167.58,19.88 164.96,19.88 162.59,20.78L158.56,22.31C156.19,23.21 153.57,23.21 151.2,22.31L147.17,20.78C144.8,19.88 142.18,19.88 139.81,20.78L135.78,22.31C133.41,23.21 130.79,23.21 128.41,22.31L124.39,20.78C122.01,19.88 119.39,19.88 117.02,20.78L112.99,22.31C110.62,23.21 108,23.21 105.63,22.31L101.6,20.78C99.23,19.88 96.61,19.88 94.24,20.78L90.21,22.31C87.84,23.21 85.22,23.21 82.85,22.31L78.82,20.78C76.45,19.88 73.83,19.88 71.45,20.78L67.43,22.31C65.05,23.21 62.43,23.21 60.06,22.31L56.03,20.78C53.66,19.88 51.04,19.88 48.67,20.78L44.64,22.31C42.27,23.21 39.65,23.21 37.28,22.31L33.25,20.78C30.88,19.88 28.26,19.88 25.89,20.78L21.86,22.31C19.49,23.21 16.87,23.21 14.49,22.31L10.47,20.78C8.09,19.88 5.47,19.88 3.1,20.78L-0.93,22.31C-3.3,23.21 -5.92,23.21 -8.29,22.31L-16,19.38"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,23.99L340.82,26.91C338.46,27.8 335.85,27.8 333.49,26.91L329.42,25.37C327.06,24.48 324.46,24.48 322.1,25.37L318.03,26.91C315.67,27.8 313.07,27.8 310.71,26.91L306.64,25.37C304.28,24.48 301.67,24.48 299.31,25.37L295.25,26.91C292.89,27.8 290.28,27.8 287.92,26.91L283.86,25.37C281.5,24.48 278.89,24.48 276.53,25.37L272.46,26.91C270.1,27.8 267.5,27.8 265.14,26.91L261.07,25.37C258.71,24.48 256.11,24.48 253.75,25.37L249.68,26.91C247.32,27.8 244.71,27.8 242.35,26.91L238.29,25.37C235.93,24.48 233.32,24.48 230.96,25.37L226.9,26.91C224.54,27.8 221.93,27.8 219.57,26.91L215.5,25.37C213.14,24.48 210.54,24.48 208.18,25.37L204.11,26.91C201.75,27.8 199.15,27.8 196.79,26.91L192.72,25.37C190.36,24.48 187.75,24.48 185.39,25.37L181.33,26.91C178.97,27.8 176.36,27.8 174,26.91L169.94,25.37C167.57,24.48 164.97,24.48 162.61,25.37L158.54,26.91C156.18,27.8 153.58,27.8 151.22,26.91L147.15,25.37C144.79,24.48 142.19,24.48 139.83,25.37L135.76,26.91C133.4,27.8 130.79,27.8 128.43,26.91L124.37,25.37C122.01,24.48 119.4,24.48 117.04,25.37L112.97,26.91C110.61,27.8 108.01,27.8 105.65,26.91L101.58,25.37C99.22,24.48 96.62,24.48 94.26,25.37L90.19,26.91C87.83,27.8 85.23,27.8 82.87,26.91L78.8,25.37C76.44,24.48 73.83,24.48 71.47,25.37L67.41,26.91C65.05,27.8 62.44,27.8 60.08,26.91L56.02,25.37C53.65,24.48 51.05,24.48 48.69,25.37L44.62,26.91C42.26,27.8 39.66,27.8 37.3,26.91L33.23,25.37C30.87,24.48 28.27,24.48 25.91,25.37L21.84,26.91C19.48,27.8 16.87,27.8 14.51,26.91L10.45,25.37C8.09,24.48 5.48,24.48 3.12,25.37L-0.94,26.91C-3.31,27.8 -5.91,27.8 -8.27,26.91L-16,23.99"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M348.55,28.59L340.82,31.51C338.46,32.41 335.85,32.41 333.49,31.51L329.42,29.98C327.06,29.09 324.46,29.09 322.1,29.98L318.03,31.51C315.67,32.41 313.07,32.41 310.71,31.51L306.64,29.98C304.28,29.09 301.67,29.09 299.31,29.98L295.25,31.51C292.89,32.41 290.28,32.41 287.92,31.51L283.86,29.98C281.5,29.09 278.89,29.09 276.53,29.98L272.46,31.51C270.1,32.41 267.5,32.41 265.14,31.51L261.07,29.98C258.71,29.09 256.11,29.09 253.75,29.98L249.68,31.51C247.32,32.41 244.71,32.41 242.35,31.51L238.29,29.98C235.93,29.09 233.32,29.09 230.96,29.98L226.9,31.51C224.54,32.41 221.93,32.41 219.57,31.51L215.5,29.98C213.14,29.09 210.54,29.09 208.18,29.98L204.11,31.51C201.75,32.41 199.15,32.41 196.79,31.51L192.72,29.98C190.36,29.09 187.75,29.09 185.39,29.98L181.33,31.51C178.97,32.41 176.36,32.41 174,31.51L169.94,29.98C167.57,29.09 164.97,29.09 162.61,29.98L158.54,31.51C156.18,32.41 153.58,32.41 151.22,31.51L147.15,29.98C144.79,29.09 142.19,29.09 139.83,29.98L135.76,31.51C133.4,32.41 130.79,32.41 128.43,31.51L124.37,29.98C122.01,29.09 119.4,29.09 117.04,29.98L112.97,31.51C110.61,32.41 108.01,32.41 105.65,31.51L101.58,29.98C99.22,29.09 96.62,29.09 94.26,29.98L90.19,31.51C87.83,32.41 85.23,32.41 82.87,31.51L78.8,29.98C76.44,29.09 73.83,29.09 71.47,29.98L67.41,31.51C65.05,32.41 62.44,32.41 60.08,31.51L56.02,29.98C53.65,29.09 51.05,29.09 48.69,29.98L44.62,31.51C42.26,32.41 39.66,32.41 37.3,31.51L33.23,29.98C30.87,29.09 28.27,29.09 25.91,29.98L21.84,31.51C19.48,32.41 16.87,32.41 14.51,31.51L10.45,29.98C8.09,29.09 5.48,29.09 3.12,29.98L-0.94,31.51C-3.31,32.41 -5.91,32.41 -8.27,31.51L-16,28.59"
        android:strokeWidth="0.75947"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.22"
        android:strokeColor="#322B3A" />
    

</vector>
```

The result I wish should be like this:
[image]

But when I implement ic_background_wave.xml as background in my Constraintlayout the wave goes beyond rounding. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens because  `<corners android:radius="16dp" />` is inside `<shape>` and it applies radius to the shape. The new item with background `android:drawable="@drawable/ic_group_wave_backg"` is drown on top. That's how Layer List works: [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList%5D)

The easiest way would be add corners to the view itself.
It's also possible to play with Layer List. E.g. move item with "ic_group_wave_backg" using:

```
  <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_group_wave_backg"
        android:top="10dp"/>
```

It will produce gap without waves on the top and on the bottom. However it's possible to add one more item with single wave and moved them similar.

Another solution is preparing svg with waves and background with rounded corners and just import as vector drawable.

All depends on the needs and main purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I can't have gaps on top and bottom and don't know how to edit SVG. Your proposal for adding rounded corners to view itself would be possible e.g. for CardView. With ConstraintLayout I know only way with shape as background - what I exactly have. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: The answers depend on the usage. Where this Constraint Layout will be used?